# pdflatex sporadic broken pipe errors when generating PDFs from .tex file

Tags: pdftex

I've written software which generates rather long PDFs from generated .tex files with pdflatex. On occasion, I'll get broken pipe errors which cause the pdf generation to fail. I have trouble recreating the errors, and the pdf generation will often work if I try it a second time.

I'm already calling pdflatex with `-interaction=nonstopmode`.

I'm looking for a way to:
prevent the broken pipe errors from occurring OR
ignore the broken pipe error and continue

Here is the error that I am getting:

```
[323] [324 </srv/www/mydomain.com/public_html/crawler/RRnKPFCjyZMKk1nUg/Images/Q
BFkqp_thumbnail1063.png
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file /srv/www/mydomain.com/public_html/crawler/RRnKPFCj
yZMKk1nUg/Images/QBFkqp_thumbnail1063.png): fflush() failed (Broken pipe)
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: As is evident from the compilation, this seems to occur with an image. [A quick online search](http://www.tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2008-June/010173.html) revealed a way to identify the problem image when using `xelatex`. How do you generate the images? I noticed you're using "underscores" in your paths. Do you specifically accommodate for this via [`grffile`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/grffile)?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842016/pdflatex-sporadic-broken-pipe-errors-when-generating-pdfs-from-tex-file?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Please tell us more about the setup: Which version of pdfTeX on which OS are you running?

Comment: @Werner: He is using `pdflatex`, not `xelatex`.

Comment: I'm running ubuntu 10.04 on a VPS at linode. I've noticed that the error occurs more often when either multiple pdfs are being created at once or the file contains 1000+ images. Is this a known error with certain versions of pdflatex? Could it perhaps be related to the limit (1024) on the number of open files? Is it possible that the images take a bit of time to close and I'm hitting that limit?

Comment: @RobertRawlingsWVU: Please try to reproduce the errors while running `strace` and study its ouput (you should probaly redirect the output with `-o`, see `man strace`).